# Using tasks (TPL) within constructors

Tags: c#, .net, static, singleton, task

Any idea why nothing is printed in console?

My research made me believe that we cant have tasks started in static constructor, but the example below doesnt even have a static constrcutor.

The reason I added the `private static readonly Foo instance = new Foo();` is because I need to implement a singleton pattern. The code is incomplete implementation of singleton pattern. I removed the code for readability.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo t = new Foo();
        Console.WriteLine("Program finished");
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    private static readonly Foo instance = new Foo();

    public Foo()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();        
        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                int r = rnd.Next();
                Bar(r);
            });
        Task.WaitAll(t);

        Console.WriteLine("Foo finished");
    }

    static void Bar(int value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, think about why you would need a singleton at all. Chances are, you *don't*. Singleton is an anti-pattern.

Comment: `but the example below doesn't even have a static constrcutor.`  It does. When you initialize a static field the way you do, the code automatically gets rewritten into a static constructor.

Comment: @KooKiz: I wasn't aware of this, then I think the below link explains the reason why http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/05/03/10159682.aspx